# Initial load of data from 3rd party API in react-redux-universal-hot-example starter kit

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, redux

In react-redux-universal-hot-example starter kit I added redux-promise to middleware and used axios to make a request to external API.

In Redux Dev Tools I see the data returned from API call but nothing is getting rendered. I suspect my workflow is wrong.

Here is what I have done:

- I added a Redux module [weatherForecast.js](https://github.com/zunperior/wear4cast/blob/master/src/redux/modules/weatherForecast.js) that contains Action Creator and Reducer
- I added a container [forecast.js](https://github.com/zunperior/wear4cast/blob/master/src/containers/Forecast/Forecast.js) where I initiate call to 3rd party API and render data. (Unfortunately I can't see any data being rendered...)
- I added forecast container to [Home](https://github.com/zunperior/wear4cast/blob/master/src/containers/Home/Home.js) screen (this part works)

Is my data loading workflow completely wrong or have I missed something minor? 
Full source code is [here](https://github.com/zunperior/wear4cast).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in combineReducers you have:

```
export default combineReducers({
  routing: routeReducer,
  reduxAsyncConnect,
  auth,
  form,
  multireducer: multireducer({
    counter1: counter,
    counter2: counter,
    counter3: counter
  }),
  info,
  widgets,
  outfits,
  weatherForecast
});
```

In your connect call you have:

```
@connect(
    state => ({forecast: state.forecast}),
    {fetchForecast}
)
```

Hence you include the state wrongly, it should be

```
state => ({forecast: state.weatherForecast.forecast}),
```

If you are starting out with Redux, I advise you not to start with a full boilerplate project, but start simple and add abstractions when you find you need them.

Comment: 1. I thought 
`@connect(
    state => ({forecast: state.forecast}),
    {fetchForecast}
)`

was same as 
 
`@connect(
    state => ({forecast: state.forecast}),
    dispatch => bindActionCreators({fetchForecast}, dispatch))
)`

I will try explicit dispatch.

2. I use redux-promise middleware to reissue action once result is available.

Comment: You are right, sorry overlooked your connect statement for the first remark

Comment: Yes, this was the issue.Thank you!
Maybe once I get more experience with React I won't make such simple mistakes.